# why getline() is returning just 1 instead of returning character no it reads

Tags: c, getline

here is my.I cannot understand why this getline() returning 1 instead of returning no of characters it read.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

FILE *fp;
if (argc!=3)
{
    printf("improper number of input\n");
    exit(1);
}

size_t len=0;
ssize_t read;
char *line=NULL;
fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
if (fp==NULL)
{
    printf("file is empty\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}



while (read=getline(&line, &len, fp)!=-1)
{
    printf("retrieved line length %zu \n",read );
    //printf("%s\n",line );
}
fclose(fp);
free(line);
}
```

And here is my output.

```
retrieved line length 1
```

I used getline() as mentioned here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html

my file contains following text:

> The official and de facto national language of Bangladesh is Modern Standard Bengali (Literary Bengali).[6][7][8][9] It serves as the lingua franca of the nation, with 98% of Bangladeshis being fluent in Bengali (including dialects) as their first language.[10][11] Within India, Bengali is the official language of the states of West Bengal, Tripura and the Barak Valley in the state of Assam. It is also spoken in different parts of the Brahmaputra valley of Assam. It is also the most widely spoken language in the Andaman and Nicobar Islands in the Bay of Bengal,[12] and is spoken by significant minorities in other states including Jharkhand, Bihar, Mizoram, Meghalaya, and Odisha. With approximately 250–300 million total speakers worldwide,[13] Bengali is usually counted as the seventh most spoken native language in the world by population

Comment: What are the exact contents of the file you tried to read with this program?  Might it possibly begin with a blank line?

Comment: BTW: `ssize_t` is signed, whereas `%zu` is for unsigned `size_t`, isn't it?

Comment: yea right. I am new to programming. can you tell me, what should i use for ssize_t. @StephanLechner

Comment: `%zd`, regarding https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: (What buffer length does `len` indicate?)

Comment: that is standard getline() use . http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html @greybeard

Comment: So, when `read` was 1, what value had been assigned to `len`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `!=` binds stronger than `=` you need to use parantheses:

```
while((read=getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
```

You basically assign the result of the comparision to `read` which is `1` if it evaluates to true and `0` otherwise.

Comment: Doh! I should have seen that.